# How far the pairs emitted by the photon has to be?

Tags: pair-production

An electron-positron pair can be emitted by a photon having enough energy. Can one say the pairs are already inside the photon (like an atom), and when got the right energy they fly off? If this proposition were true, how would the photon wavelength related to the pair separation?

Comment: A photon can't produce an electron-positron pair in a vacuum (momentum conservation is violated in that process), so that should tell you the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

> Can one say the pairs are already inside the photon (like an atom), and when got the right energy they fly off

No. A photon is a photon - it doesn't "contain" a positron-electron pair in any meaningful sense.

Given the right conditions, it is possible for that photon to disappear and for a positron-electron pair to appear in its stead, but that does *not* mean that they were "already inside" it.